# How can I check for models with the same relations?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Given:

```
App.Chart = DS.Model.extend({
  tags: DS.hasMany('tag'),

  sameTag: function() {
    var id = this.get('id');
    var tags = this.get('tags');
    return this.store.filter('chart', function(q) {
      return Ember.isEqual(q.get('tags'), tags);
    });
  }.property('tags')
});


App.Tag = DS.Model.extend();
```

Fails because `Ember.isEqual(q.get('tags'), tags)` on the OrderedSets is `false` even when two models have the same tags and they both have their tags loaded.  Instead I've had to make a calculated property that gives me something that works with `Ember.isEqual`:

```
App.Chart = DS.Model.extend({
  tags: DS.hasMany('tag'),

  sameTag: function() {
    var id = this.get('id');
    var tags = this.get('_tagsKey');
    return this.store.filter('chart', function(q) {
      return Ember.isEqual(q.get('_tagsKey'), tags);
    });
  }.property(),

  _tagsKey: function(){
    var tags = [];
    this.get('tags').forEach(function(tag){
      tags.push(tag.id);
    });
    return tags.join(",");
  }.property('tags')
});
```

Which is a quite convoluted way of going about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your idea right:

```
sameTag: function() {
  var tags = this.get('tags')
    , ids = tags.mapBy('id').join('');

  return this.store.filter('chart', function(q) {
    return q.get('tags').mapBy('id').join('') === ids;
  });
}.property('tags')
```

This is still a bit expensive, but should do the job.